# Instantiating file object

Tags: java

I have this very basic question.

1. Does `File file = new File("fileName");` actually create a file if one does not exist?
2. What happens if the file already exists in that location?

Are there any good tutorials you can point me to so I can read more about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it does not. The File object represents an abstract notion of a file, which may exist, but doesn't need to. Note that the File object can also point to a directory (which may or may not exist).

Answer (score 3):

Usually you can find out information about java in the api

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 3):

No, if you want to create an empty file, use [createNewFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29)

```
File myFile = new File("test.txt");
myFile.createNewFile();
```

Answer (score 3):

No, calling the objects constructor simply creates an instance of the `File`-Class.
Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

```
 File(File parent, String child):
```

> Creates a new File instance from a parent abstract pathname and a child pathname string.

The call of the `createNewFile()`- Method writes the file to disk.

> Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname
>   if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist.

You can simply check it by creating a `File`-object with a non existing file path and calling the `File.exists()`; method.

```
if (!file.exists()) {
//File does not exist
}
```